# Using PowerShell switch command with changing values

Tags: powershell

I am trying to use the switch command to select something out of an array.  The array can change sizes depending on information from another spread sheet.

For example:

```
C:\> $Test = A
C:\> $ListA
    Item_One       Item_Two
    --------       --------
    A              1
    B              2
    C              3
```

I want to create a switch that will return the corresponding value of `Item_Two` when `$Test` is checked against `$ListA.Item_One`.  The problem I am having is, `$ListA` can change the number of values depending on the situation.  The switch statement I was thinking was something like this:

```
switch ($Test)
{
    $ListA.Item_One {write-host $ListA.Item_two}
    default {"Not found"}
}
```

When I run this code, it just ends up on the default, I can't get it to trigger off the `$ListA.Item_One` section.  Is there a way to do this, or how else can I do what I'm trying to do?  I know I can use a for-each loop, but I looking to see if there were other ways.  I could imagine if the list got to large, it would take a long time to sift through.  Right now the list is only 5-10 items, but it could grow to over 40+ within a year.

Edit:  I am populating the list through a .csv:

```
$listA = Import C:\File.csv
```

Comment: Can you add the code for how you populate the list?

Comment: I added the information to the main post.  It's just coming from a .csv file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With what you've done,  $listA has no element named "Item_One" so that expression is effectively NULL
It's an array, and if you want to get "A" out of $listA, you need to use $listA[0].Item_One and $ListA[0].Item_two
Without knowing more about this situation not quite sure what to suggest...
Do you really have so many items you need a CSV?
If not try a hash table

```
PS C:\temp> $listA = import-csv .\list.csv
PS C:\temp> $listA

Item_One                                Item_Two
--------                                --------
A                                       1
B                                       2
C                                       3


PS C:\temp> $listA.gettype()

IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType
-------- -------- ----                                     --------
True     True     Object[]                                 System.Array


PS C:\temp> $listA.Item_One

PS C:\temp> $listA[0].Item_One
A

PS C:\temp> switch ($Test)
>> {
>> $listA[0].Item_One {write-host $ListA[0].Item_two}
>> default {"Not found"}
>> }
>>
1

# Hash table example
$hash=@{"A"=1;"B"=2;"C"=3}
$hash.A
1
```

## New after Nick's 7/9 comment:

I don't think the case/switch structure is a good fit for this case.
This seems like it will do what you need.

```
$listA | foreach {
    if ($_.item_one -eq "A") {
        # do something
        write-host $_.item_two
    } elseif ($_.item_one -eq "B") {
        # do something different
        write-host $_.item_two
    } else {
        $found = $false
    }
}
if ($found -eq $false) {
    write-host "default"
}
```

Depending on your needs, the IF clause could also be begin like this

```
if ($_.item_one -match "A|B|C") {
```

Comment: The list is about 10 entries now, but once everything works it will expand to 40+ entries.  Also, I used Item_One and Item_two as an example, but there are currently Items 1 through 7, with the potential for more to be added later.  

The items are a domain name, fqdn, the full name of the primary DC, the IP address of the DC, authentication information, and software version.  I work in a test lab, and this information can change regularly.  I am automating some basic checks for a few decks.  Once I get this working, this script will become a template for more thorough check on all our decks.

Comment: That's what I thought, but I wanted to be sure. I currently am using a ForEach loop, so I will continue with that.  Thank you for the help.